# How to allocate memory in this case?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have pointers in main for which I don't know it's size. A function returns this pointer to main. Inside the function I can calulate the size of pointer and hence need to store values in them and return them to main. How to modify/allocate memory in this case.

```
int main()
{
    int *row_value, *col_value;
    col_row_value(row_value,col_value);
    ...
    return(0);
}

void col_row_value(row_value,col_value)
{
    // how to allocate/modify memory for row_value and col_value and store data
    // for example would like to allocate memory here
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        row_value[i]=i;
        col_value[i]=i;
    }
}
```

I tried something like this,it doesn't work

```
int main()
{
    int *row_value, *col_value;
    row_value=NULL;
    col_value=NULL;
    col_row_value(&row_value,&col_value);
    ...
    return(0);
}

void col_row_value(int **row_value,int **col_value)
{
    // how to allocate/modify memory for row_value and col_value and store data
    // for example would like to allocate memory here
    int i;
    *row_value=(int*)realloc(*row_value,10*sizeof(int));
    *col_value=(int*)realloc(*col_value,10*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        row_value[i]=i;
        col_value[i]=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Program design-wise: why doesn't the code using the variables know their size? Why do you want a function that is only concerned with setting values to also do an entirely different task, namely dynamic memory allocation? Why can't you do that from the caller?

Comment: Purely as a matter of interest, why are you leaving location 0 untouched?

Comment: I don't know whether this is the case, but in general it'd be a good idea that you return in col_row_vaule the size of allocated fields.

Comment: In many situation we will not know exact size of the array. Take a simple example of matrix-matrix multiplication, we don't know non-zero elements of the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
*row_value=(int*)realloc(row_value*,10*sizeof(int));
```

should be:

```
*row_value = realloc(*row_value,10*sizeof(int));
                 /** ^ **/
```

Note the cast is unnecessary. Assign the result of `realloc()` to a temporary pointer in case the reallocation fails which would mean the original memory would be inaccessible.

```
int* tmp = realloc(*row_value, 10 * sizeof(*tmp));
if (tmp)
{
    *row_value = tmp;
}
```

Note the `for` loop does not assign a value to the first element in `row_value` or `col_value`:

```
for(i=1;i<10;i++)
```

as it starts at index `1` and the assignments within the `for` should be:

```
(*row_value)[i] = i;
(*col_value)[i] = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version is essentially correct.

You need to say:

```
realloc(*row_value, 10 * sizeof(int));
//     ^^^
```

Mind the star!

If it helps, rename your function arguments to:

```
col_row_value(int ** ptr_to_row_ptr, int ** ptr_to_col_ptr);
```

That way, you won't confuse yourself as much.